# Why does my code need an overload with HashSet<T> instead of ISet<T>?

Tags: c#

I've got the below method:

```
    private string TickIfHeadingPresent<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, ISet<TValue>> data, TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        ISet<TValue> set;
        return data.TryGetValue(key, out set) && set.Contains(value) ? "<i class='icon-check'></i>" : String.Empty;
    }
```

Sometimes I call the method with an object I've just created, where C# knows that I specifically have a `Dictionary<whatever, HashSet<something>>.`

In those cases I get the error:

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,
>   System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<string>>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,
>   System.Collections.Generic.ISet<string>>'

That confuses me because `HashSet<T>` is a subset of `ISet<T>` - surely any code that accepts `ISet<T>` won't mind getting a specific sort of set?

The "fix" according to Visual Studio is to add a duplicate method with a more specific overload:

```
    // I have no idea why this won't just hit the ISet overload...
    private string TickIfHeadingPresent<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, HashSet<TValue>> data, TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        HashSet<TValue> set;
        return data.TryGetValue(key, out set) && set.Contains(value) ? "<i class='icon-check'></i>" : String.Empty;
    }
```

Is there any way to write my code so that I only have to define the method once?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you have `Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>` as you describe. Suppose you somehow would able to pass it as `Dictionary<string, ISet<string>>`. If that were the case, you can now add other objects that implement `ISet<string>` to this dictionary, not only `HashSet<string>`. So for example you can now add `SortedSet<string>` to your dictionary. But `SortedSet` is not `HashSet`, nor it derives from `HashSet<string>`, and your original `Dictionary` could only contain `HashSet`s. That example shows *why* it is not allowed to convert from `Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>` to `Dictionary<string, ISet<string>>`.

Now, with some interfaces you cannot perform such operation which will violate type safety. For example take `IEnumerable<T>`. If you have a method like:

```
 private string TickIfHeadingPresent<TKey, TValue>(IEnumerable<ISet<TKey>> data, TKey key, TValue value)
```

Now you *can* pass `List<HashSet<string>>` as `IEnumerable<ISet<string>>`. You cannot add new item to `IEnumerable<T>`, nor can you do any other operation of this sort which will violate type safety. This is ensured because IEnumerable is defined like this:

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
```

"out" keyword means T is covariant and compiler will ensure that no method on this interface can violate that (basically it will not allow to use type T as parameter to any method, only as return type).

Answer (score 0):

As explained this is a variance problem. Here's an alternative approach that allows you to still only have one `TickIfHeadingPresent` method.

What you need in `TickIfHeadingPresent` is not necessarily that the values in  `data` are ***of*** a particular collection type; rather, you need that the values in `data` *can tell you whether they include a specific `value`*. So if you do this:

```
private string TickIfHeadingPresent<TKey, TValue, TValueSet>
    (Dictionary<TKey, TValueSet> data, TKey key, TValue value)
    where TValueSet : ICollection<TValue>
{
    TValueSet set;
    return data.TryGetValue(key, out set) && set.Contains(value) ? "<i class='icon-check'></i>" : String.Empty;
}
```

then you can call this method with both a `Dictionary<whatever, HashSet<something>>` and also with a `Dictionary` any other `ISet<>`-implementing collection as the type of the value.

All we've done here is tell the compiler that we need the type of the values in the dictionary to implement `ICollection<>` *of the same type as we're going to be looking up in it*, and then the compiler knows it can safely call `Contains` with `value` on whatever it pulls out of the dictionary. Type inference means that although this method has a more complicated signature, we still don't need to explicitly specify the type parameters.